# How to get a components on Layout using react-router when on a specific route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an index.js file which has all the routes.

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
      <IndexRedirect to={'dashboard'}/>
      <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path="donors" >
        <IndexRoute component={Donors} />
        <Route path=":id" component={SingleDonor} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="repository" component={Repository} />
      <Route path="groups"  background={'premium'} premiumText={'groups is a premium feature'}>
        <IndexRoute component={Groups} />
        <Route path=":name" component={SingleGroup} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="campaigns" component={Campaigns} background={'premium'} premiumText={'campaings is a premium feature'}/>
      <Route path="followups" component={Followups} background={'premium'} premiumText={'followups is a premium feature'} />
      <Route path="settings" component={Settings}  background={'premium'} premiumText={'settings is a premium feature'}/>
      <Route path="subscriptions" component={Subscription} background={'premium'} premiumText={'creating a great product for the best price'} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
  </Router>
```

I want to show a component inside TopMenu component of Layout.js only when the user is on `/donor/1` route

This is my Layout render method

```
<div>
      <Sidebar userData={this.state.userData} ngo={this.state.ngo}
              lockPortal={this.lockPortal}
      />
      <TopMenu userData={this.state.userData}
              logoutUser={this.logoutUser}
      />
      {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ngo: this.state.ngo })}
</div>
```

What is the solution to this. Also if this is a duplicate can someone please redirect me to the possible solution as I was unable to find it. Thanks in advance.